# I have table with long notes. In the longtable and threeparttable environment, how to split long notes into two pages?

Tags: longtable, threeparttable

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}  %%% This should come before longtable and it is not tablenotes but TableNotes
  \small
  \item[1]  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
   hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
   hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa
  hereaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaa

  \end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
page}}\\
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
%\newpage
%\pagebreak

\insertTableNotes         %% this added
\endlastfoot

  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  %\bottomrule
  \end{longtable}

  \end{ThreePartTable}
  %\end{landscape}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me for long notes with 'a' there. Just in order to  create a long note.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! To simulate long text (in notes, in your case), you can use packages `lipsum` and for text only rite for example `lipsum[1]` (for one paragraph of dummy text) or `\lispum[1-9]` for 9 paragraphs or just `\lipsum` for few page long text. Beside `lipsum`exist also other packages, like `blindtext`, etc ..

Comment: Zarko, Thank you! Could anyone help to answer how to split the long notes into two pages in threeparttable environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `longtable` supports `\footnote` within the body, the resulting footnote won't break either.  At least, not past the end of the longtable.  You have to use `\footnotetext` after the `longtable`.  Since `longtable` isn't a float, you don't have to worry about it moving.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
page}}\\
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
%\newpage
%\pagebreak
\footnotemark
\endlastfoot

  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\


  %\bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \footnotetext{here - \lipsum[1-6]}
  %\end{landscape}

  \end{document}
```

---

Here is a macro to write a fake footnote as text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakefootnote}[2][\empty]% #1 = footnote mark (optional), #2 = text
{\bgroup
  \ifx\empty#1\relax\else
    \csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname=#1\relax
    \xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
  \fi
  \par\bigskip\footnoterule
  \reset@font\footnotesize
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\footnotesep
  \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
  \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
  \color@begingroup
    \@makefntext{\rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#2\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
 \color@endgroup%
 \footnoterule\bigskip\par% add extra line at end
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

test\footnote[1]{real footnote}
fake\footnotemark[2]
\fakefootnote[2]{\lipsum[1-8]}

\end{document}
```

---

As it turns out, you can use ThreePartTable just to print the notes, and use \footnotemark[...] inside longtable.  Since neither is a float, they will print consecutively.

Note: You have to use ThreePartTable together with tablenotes.  Using threeparttable or TableNotes won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrr}
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous
page}}\\
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Grp 2} &  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\textit{n}=500)} &  \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{SD} & p-value \\
  \midrule    
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\footnotemark[1]
\endlastfoot

  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
  Variable & 11.11 & 1.11 & 11.11 & 1.11 & 0.111 \\
 \end{longtable}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{tablenotes}  %%% This should come before longtable and it is not tablenotes but TableNotes
  \small
  \item[1]  \lipsum[1-6]
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
  %\end{landscape}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: @ John Kormylo, Thank you! This is exact what I need. One more question, is it possible to move the rest of the notes up from the bottom of second page?

Comment: actually,  it is from the bottom of third page instead of second page.

Comment: Footnotes are implemented as bottom floats (except inside minipages).  It might be easier just to write the footnote as text.

Comment: thank you so much! You definitely help me out of  one of tables in my thesis.

Comment: Fakefootnote works very well! Thank you so much!!@JohnKormylo

Comment: I have tried in threeparttable enviroment. Unfortunately, long notes still could not be splited into multiple pages.

Comment: You don't need threepartable.  Just replace \footnotetext with \fakefootnote.

Comment: Considering other tables in my thesis are  in threeparttable environment, I do have interests trying a consistent format for all tables.

Comment: So what you really want are fake tablenotes.