# Issues with footnotes using wrapping parbox with longtable, threeparttable and tablenotes

Tags: footnotes, longtable, parbox, tablenotes, threeparttablex

I have an issue with footnote not showing up when I wrap the threeparttable/longtable with a parbox.
If I remove the wrapping parbox from the code below, the footnote show up under the table, as I want it to.

Update - for clarification: The reason for wrapping the table are that in the complete document I need to wrap a couple of longtables so that they "group" and don't get splitted on different pages. So a solution to do the grouping in another way could also be the solution for my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] {\scriptsize testfootnot}
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{p{50mm} }
Col1\tabularnewline
\endhead
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
Value with footnote \quad\tnote{a}\tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
} %end parbox
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you wrap the table with a `\parbox`?

Comment: I have three longtables that needs to "stick together" so that I don't get a new page in the middle of the three tables. I found that a parbox solves that problem. The whole "document" can have unlimited number of these "three longtable groups". It's a generated report with configurable header and footer, so I can't know in advance how it will be printed.

Comment: If it doesn't break across pages, don't use longtable.  That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It can break across pages, that's why we use longtable. But I must admit that we haven't tested how that will work with the parbox. But the parbox-wrapping is optional in our software, so customers who need the parbox-wrapping usually don't have enough content in the table so that it needs more than one page. But it will probably be hard for us to change the use of longtable or not, just depending on the parbox-wrapping configuration.

Comment: Also, foothotes are not compatible with \parbox.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314375/why-does-parbox-lose-footnotes?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.1713

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. That was the kind of answer I wanted, even though I would have prefered a solution for the problem, of course =) So if I understand the info in the link, minipage is the solution. But isn't minipage kind of a no-no?

Comment: Footonotes in a minipage appear inside the minipage, not at the bottom of the page.  They also normally use * and \dagger etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried to change "\parbox{\textwidth}{" with "\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}" together with "\end{minipage}" but the problem is still there.. Any ideas why?

Comment: No clue.  I do know that threeparttable and longtable both support footnotes using different approaches, that threeparttable is supposed to be inside a table environment (one page only) while longtable is not.  In fact, longtable is not supposed to be inside any other environment, nor does it support twocolumn.  You might check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h