# Make longtable notes fit to page

Tags: longtabu

I used longtable and threeparttablex to make table notes. I wonder the way to adjust table notes to fit page. Also, if possible, I want to hide the endfoot line. Any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabu} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize,bf]{caption} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 

\begin{document}
\centering
\linespread{1}
\footnotesize
\begin{ThreePartTable}

\begin{TableNotes}
        \item\textbf{Notes}: Insert Whatever Important Notes hHere.
\end{TableNotes}

\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccc}
\caption{\textbf{Insert the Table Caption}} \\
\toprule
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{B/M}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}    \textbf{Size} & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5 \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
        \caption{\textbf{Continued}} \\
\toprule
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{B/M}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}    \textbf{Size} & 1  & 2  & 3  & 4  & 5 \\
\midrule  
\endhead
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Continued on Next Page}} \\   \bottomrule
\endfoot
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{End of Table}} \\  \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot

   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{a} \\
1  & 0.305 & 0.244 & -0.270 & -0.829*** & -0.846* \\
   & (1.24) & (1.24) & (-1.44) & (-3.61) & (-1.66) \\
2  & 0.787*** & 0.357** & -0.083 & -0.371 & -0.995 \\
   & (4.68) & (2.45) & (-0.50) & (-1.01) & (-1.43) \\
3  & 0.898*** & 0.472*** & 0.006 & -0.847** & -1.16 \\
   & (6.22) & (3.20) & (0.03) & (-2.28) & (-1.54) \\
4  & 0.793*** & 0.319** & 0.062 & -0.274 & -1.93*** \\
   & (5.90) & (2.00) & (0.25) & (-0.61) & (-2.81) \\
5  & 0.732*** & 0.367*** & -0.088 & -0.343 & -0.857 \\
   & (10.04) & (2.85) & (-0.40) & (-0.96) & (-1.31) \\
\midrule
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{b} \\
1  & 0.815*** & 0.838*** & 0.873*** & 0.854*** & 0.580*** \\
   & (12.19) & (16.55) & (15.31) & (13.48) & (3.63) \\
2  & 0.862*** & 0.826*** & 0.793*** & 0.802*** & 1.358*** \\
   & (17.95) & (20.88) & (18.61) & (8.31) & (7.43) \\
3  & 0.915*** & 0.875*** & 0.845*** & 0.867*** & 1.068*** \\
   & (21.92) & (21.34) & (16.40) & (8.98) & (5.88) \\
4  & 0.930*** & 0.881*** & 0.874*** & 1.052*** & 0.663*** \\
   & (22.84) & (17.97) & (11.98) & (8.37) & (3.96) \\
5  & 0.813*** & 0.813*** & 0.815*** & 0.815*** & 0.939*** \\
   & (40.48) & (21.97) & (12.98) & (8.02) & (4.94) \\
\midrule

\pagebreak
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{hml} \\
1  & \textbf{0.694***} & \textbf{0.693***} & \textbf{0.829***} & \textbf{0.770***} & 0.477 \\
   & \textbf{(8.31)} & \textbf{(7.81)} & \textbf{(8.40)} & \textbf{(6.86)} & (1.47) \\
2  & \textbf{0.724***} & \textbf{0.592***} & \textbf{0.584***} & \textbf{0.455**} & \textbf{0.991***} \\
   & \textbf{(8.68)} & \textbf{(9.91)} & \textbf{(8.16)} & \textbf{(2.47)} & (3.73) \\
3  & \textbf{0.465***} & \textbf{0.561***} & \textbf{0.455***} & \textbf{0.655***} & -0.261 \\
   & \textbf{(6.59)} & \textbf{(8.61)} & \textbf{(5.11)} & \textbf{(4.63)} & (-0.74) \\
4  & \textbf{0.469***} & \textbf{0.489***} & \textbf{0.370***} & \textbf{1.007***} & 0.158 \\
   & (6.58) & (5.57) & (3.31) & (5.75) & (0.46) \\
5  & 0.0532 & \textbf{0.188***} & \textbf{0.397***} & \textbf{0.311*} & -0.142 \\
   & (1.52) & (3.12) & (4.11) & (1.71) & (-0.44) \\
\midrule
   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{R2} \\
1  & 0.589 & 0.693 & 0.745 & 0.650 & 0.188 \\
2  & 0.760 & 0.806 & 0.740 & 0.381 & 0.269 \\
3  & 0.794 & 0.774 & 0.630 & 0.381 & 0.159 \\
4  & 0.813 & 0.730 & 0.494 & 0.389 & 0.117 \\
5  & 0.908 & 0.753 & 0.530 & 0.310 & 0.168 \\
\bottomrule\
\end{longtabu}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), a complete small test document that others can use to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: tabu is not maintained. Read the readme here before continuing to use it: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/.

Comment: Why not simply use a longtable? With `\begin{longtable}{cccccc}` you will get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NVw7.png You also seem to be able to fit the whole table into a single page (remove `\pagebreak`), so actually don't even need `longtable` at all and could simply use a normel `tabular` in combination with the `threeparttable` package.

Comment: I deleted some content in the example, so it looks like a single table could do the trick. I did not use longtable, becasue longtabu can adjust the table fit to page easily. In fact, you get the notes fit to table, because the table was not adjusted to fit the page in the fist place. Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h