# Table caption floating out of table

Tags: captions, alignment

I have a Table with caption, which I arrange using the `caption` package. In one `longtable` for which I decreased font size to 4.9pt (I know, small), the table caption is too far left, hanging out of the table.

[image: problem]

When I increase the font to 5pt, the problem vanishes. Changing `\captionsetup[..., margin=1em, ...]` to `2em` does not help at all, the caption is not even moving one bit. I cannot provide a full MWE but I do have the preamble of my table:

```
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5pt}   
\fontsize{4.9}{4.9}\selectfont
\begin{TableNotes}
\item\textit{Notes:}  ...
\end{TableNotes}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline, textfont=it, margin=1em, font=tiny}
\begin{longtable}{lcccccccccccccccccc}
\caption{Some Table} \label{tab:some} \\
\toprule    
...[headers]
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Some Table (continued)} \\
\toprule    
...
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really possible to solve without some code. Could you please provide a minimal code example producing this?

Comment: I have added the preamble of the table.

Comment: Do you supply your readers with a magnifying glass?

Comment: Longtable provides a custom \caption, so \captionsetup probably has no effect.  OTOH, I'm not sure if it supports \caption*.  Also, you can start ThreePartTable after the longtable is done.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h

Comment: why can you not provide a MWE? Not doing so just makes it hard for anyone to help you.