# Table is not centred, footnote not placed at the end of the table

Tags: tables

The table is long and not centred and the footnote isn't placec at the end of the table.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}% for\doublespacing

\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}%new

\begin{document}


 \section{Baseline behavioral measurements}

 
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Baseline behavioral measurements}
\begin{tabular}[t]{llllllll}
\hline

 &  &  &    &   Baseline Locomotion (cm)  &  & &\\
ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\


\hline
 

SD & 1 & 0.027 &0.000 & 0.870& control & 1100 ± 237 &24 \\
 
   &      &      &     &     &  SD     & 1108 ± 193  & 54  \\
PhA &   1&  8.291**& 0.101& 0.005&  PhA- &  1163 ± 188 &39\\

 &      &      &     &     & PhA+ & 1047 ± 209&     39\\
 
SD \texttimes PhA&  1&  1.713&  0.023&  0.195   & & & \\        
Error & 74& &    &   &   &   &      \\


\hline
LT & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD & N\\
\hline
SD & 1& 1.109&  0.015&  0.296&  Control &1405 ± 225& 23\\
  &  &       &         &     &  SD &    1461 ± 223& 54\\
PhA &   1&  25.147**&   0.256&  0.000&  PhA- &  1564 ± 189 &    38\\
   &     &        &       &           &PhA+ &   1327 ± 194 &    39\\
SD \texttimes PhA & 1&  0.071&  0.001&  0.790   &  &   &\\      
 Error&     73  &    &    &    &   &  &  \\                 
  \hline
&     &     &    &  Baseline SIR    &       &     &        \\
ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\
\hline
SD &    1&  0.194   &0.003& 0.661   &Control &  117.16 ± 38.1 & 24\\
   &   &          &     &          &  SD &  122.07 ± 58.5&  51\\
PhA &   1&  2.280&  0.031&  0.136&  PhA- &  131.74 ± 52.99&     36\\
    &   &       &      &    &   PhA+ &  110.12 ± 50.07&     39\\
SD\texttimes PhA&   1&  669.481&    0.003&  0.621   &  &  & \\  
Error &     71&    &    &    &   &   &   \\
\hline
LT&     df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\
\hline
SD&     1&  0.301&  0.005&  0.585&  Control&    136.81 ± 41.13&  23\\
 &       &     &        &      &    SD &    131.59 ± 40.44&     45\\
 PhA &  1&  1.896&  0.029&  0.173&  PhA- &  140.12 ± 45.8   & 34\\
    &   &       &     &    &    PhA+&   126.58 ± 33.6&  34\\
SD\texttimes PhA &  1&  0.038&  0.001&  0.846   &   &  & \\ 
Error&  64  &   &  &  &  &  &   \\
\hline
 &     &     &    &  Baseline Sociability score   &       &     &        \\   
 ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\
\hline
SD &    1&  0.643   &0.009& 0.425&  Control     &0.36 ± 0.09 &  24\\
   &    &           &   &       & SD &  0.38 ± 0.08 &   54\\
PhA &   1&  0.981&  0.013   &0.325& PhA- &  0.38 ± 0.07 &   39\\
   &   &        &      &            &PhA+ & 0.36 ± 0.09 &   39\\
SD\texttimes PhA &  1&  0   &0  &0.882  &  &   &    \\      
Error&  74&    &    &    &    &    &   \\
\hline
LT&     df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\
\hline
 SD &   1&  0   &0& 0.984&  Control &   0.35 ± 0.07 &   23\\
     &    &     &   &    &  SD &    0.35 ± 0.06 &   53\\
PhA &   1&  7.119**&    0.09&   0.009&  PhA- &  0.34 ± 0.06 &   37\\
    &    &      &       &     & PhA+&   0.37 ± 0.06 &   39\\
 SD\texttimes PhA & 1&  1.682&  0.023   &0.199  &   &   &        \\
Error&  72&   & & & & & \\
   \hline
 LT&    df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\  
\hline



\label{table:7}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%



     % This is footnote
\begin{minipage}{10cm}

\small Note:
\textit{p} < .05 = *, \textit{p} < .01 = **
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: The `minipage` with the notes is outside the `table`, therefore the (oversized) table is explicitly allowed to float behind it. For table notes → [`threeparttable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable)

Comment: You table is wider than the width of the text area. So it overlaps into the margin. Either make the text area wider, reduce the width of the table or explicitly allow the table to use parts of the right an the left margin.

Comment: How can I reduce the width of the table then?

Comment: Reducing the width is a question of design. *You* have to find out and decide, which columns can be made smaller without changing the semantic and with keeping them readable. *You* have to decide, e.g., if the table can be spitted. This is nothing we can do for you. But I've show one example of what could be done in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long tables you should use `longtable`, to allow them to break across pages.

To avoid, that the “Baseline …” headings increase the column width, you can use, e.g., `\multicolumn`, to place them centered across all columns.

I would also recommend to use `booktabs` for more space above/below the rules.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% should not be needed
\usepackage{graphicx} % Not used in the example!
\usepackage{setspace}% Not used in the example!

\usepackage{indentfirst}% for indent the first line
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\usepackage{ragged2e}% Not used in the example!
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{xltabular}% Not used in the example!
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}%new
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\section{Baseline behavioral measurements}

 
\begin{longtable}{llllllll}
  \caption{Baseline behavioral measurements}\label{table:7}\\
  \endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Baseline behavioral measurements \emph{(continued)}}\\
  \endhead
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Baseline Locomotion (cm)}\\
  ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\
  \midrule
  SD & 1 & 0.027 &0.000 & 0.870& control & 1100 ± 237 &24 \\
     &      &      &     &     &  SD     & 1108 ± 193  & 54  \\
  PhA &   1&  8.291**& 0.101& 0.005&  PhA- &  1163 ± 188 &39\\
      &      &      &     &     & PhA+ & 1047 ± 209&     39\\
  SD \texttimes PhA&  1&  1.713&  0.023&  0.195   & & & \\*        
  Error & 74& &    &   &   &   &      \\
  \midrule
  LT & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD & N\\
  \midrule
  SD & 1& 1.109&  0.015&  0.296&  Control &1405 ± 225& 23\\
     &  &       &         &     &  SD &    1461 ± 223& 54\\
  PhA &   1&  25.147**&   0.256&  0.000&  PhA- &  1564 ± 189 &    38\\
      &     &        &       &           &PhA+ &   1327 ± 194 &    39\\
  SD \texttimes PhA & 1&  0.071&  0.001&  0.790   &  &   &\\*
  Error&     73  &    &    &    &   &  &  \\                 
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Baseline SIR}\\*
  ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\*
  \midrule
  SD &    1&  0.194   &0.003& 0.661   &Control &  117.16 ± 38.1 & 24\\
     &   &          &     &          &  SD &  122.07 ± 58.5&  51\\
  PhA &   1&  2.280&  0.031&  0.136&  PhA- &  131.74 ± 52.99&     36\\
      &   &       &      &    &   PhA+ &  110.12 ± 50.07&     39\\
  SD\texttimes PhA&   1&  669.481&    0.003&  0.621   &  &  & \\*
  Error &     71&    &    &    &   &   &   \\
  \midrule
  LT&     df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\
  \midrule
  SD&     1&  0.301&  0.005&  0.585&  Control&    136.81 ± 41.13&  23\\
    &       &     &        &      &    SD &    131.59 ± 40.44&     45\\
  PhA &  1&  1.896&  0.029&  0.173&  PhA- &  140.12 ± 45.8   & 34\\
    &   &       &     &    &    PhA+&   126.58 ± 33.6&  34\\
  SD\texttimes PhA &  1&  0.038&  0.001&  0.846   &   &  & \\ 
  Error&  64  &   &  &  &  &  &   \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Baseline Sociability score}\\*
   ST & df & F - value & pη2 &P - value& & M \textpm StD& N\\*
  \midrule
  SD &    1&  0.643   &0.009& 0.425&  Control     &0.36 ± 0.09 &  24\\
     &    &           &   &       & SD &  0.38 ± 0.08 &   54\\
  PhA &   1&  0.981&  0.013   &0.325& PhA- &  0.38 ± 0.07 &   39\\
     &   &        &      &            &PhA+ & 0.36 ± 0.09 &   39\\
  SD\texttimes PhA &  1&  0   &0  &0.882  &  &   &    \\*
  Error&  74&    &    &    &    &    &   \\
  \midrule
  LT&     df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\
  \midrule
   SD &   1&  0   &0& 0.984&  Control &   0.35 ± 0.07 &   23\\
     &    &     &   &    &  SD &    0.35 ± 0.06 &   53\\
  PhA &   1&  7.119**&    0.09&   0.009&  PhA- &  0.34 ± 0.06 &   37\\
    &    &      &       &     & PhA+&   0.37 ± 0.06 &   39\\
  SD\texttimes PhA & 1&  1.682&  0.023   &0.199  &   &   &        \\*
  Error&  72&   & & & & & \\
    \midrule
   LT&    df &    F - value & pη2     &p - value  & & M ± StD &   N\\  
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}



     % This is footnote
\begin{minipage}{10cm}

\small Note:
\textit{p} < .05 = *, \textit{p} < .01 = **
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Other changes like using `siunitx` could also make sense. But I've tried to reduce the changes to a minimum. However, I would also recommend to think about splitting the long table into several smaller (sub-)tables. Maybe even using package `subcaption` would make sense. But I cannot decide this.

Comment: Oh thank you for this wonderful solution!

Comment: Actually, longtable supports normal footnotes, although it may have a problem if the footnotes extend beyond the end of the longtable (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h).